# Gradle - Extracting a zip into a specific directory

Tags: gradle

I have a zip file as a dependency in my gradle build script. I am able to extract and reference files from it, but it is getting extracted into a folder inside my build directory (I guess that's the default behavior). Is it possible to change this behavior and make gradle extract the zip into a directory of my choice? For ex., I would like to have the zip extracted into a folder directly under my project root.

Thank you in advance for your help.

This is the code snippet:

`FileCollection ZipFiles = files(configurations.new_config.findAll
        { it.name.endsWith('.zip') })

FileCollection zipFileContents = files(ZipFiles.collect { zipTree(it) })

return files(zipFileContents.findAll { it.name.endsWith('.jar') })`

Actually I have this inside a function. The last line returns only the jar files within the zip. The line before that does the extraction.

Comment: If you post the build script snippet that extracts the zip file contents I can suggest how it might be fixed.

Comment: FileCollection ZipFiles = files(configurations.new_config.findAll
        { it.name.endsWith('.zip') })
FileCollection zipFileContents = files(pdkZipFiles.collect { zipTree(it) })
return files(zipFileContents.findAll { it.name.endsWith('.jar') }) //Actually I have this inside a function. The last line returns only the jar files within the zip. The line before that does the extraction.

Comment: sorry for the bad formatting in the comments. I have edited my question by adding code. Thanks.

Comment: I don't see how these lines are doing the extraction to the file system. Could you maybe create a minimal example and post that?